# LWJGL Rotating one object only

Tags: java, matrix, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I am trying to rotate only one of two objects in my scene which I created in Java using
LWJGL.
Now, when I try to rotate one object, it doesn't rotate around it's center but in large circles. After searching on Google I now know that it should work like this :

```
glPushMatrix();
glBegin();

  //Code in here

glEnd();
glRotate();
glPopMatrix();
```

But it's not working for me. The object isn't rotating. This is my render code :

```
    public void render() {

        glPushMatrix();

            glRotatef(rotate, 0, 1.0f, 0);                   

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

                // Top
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                // Bottom
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);
                // One side
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                // Moar sides
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                // Last side
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX - size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                // Real last side
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ - size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY + size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ + size);
                glVertex3f(-centerX + size, centerY - size, -centerZ - size);

            glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        rotate++;
}
```

I now tried fixing this problem for hours but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()` before you draw the quads.

Remember that the order of transformations is important. Rotation is always about `0,0,0`, so if you translate first it will sort of 'orbit' around a point in a circle. If you want it to rotate around its own axis (which you probably do) rotate first, then translate.

There is a section in this article about the order of transformations.

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

Comment: Thats not working, I tried that to. When I do it like this, the cube isnt rotating around its own axis.

Comment: Edited answer. Rotate first, then translate.

Comment: But even if I only rotate and dont translate, it does nothing.